# Uploading images to S3 without ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, amazon-s3, mongomapper

I'm trying to upload files to S3 where the rails project does not use the ActiveRecord it uses the MongoMapper. Is there any gem which could help me to do this task? I have tried the mm-carrierwave (I have tryied to adapt the Ryane Bate example in RailsCasts) but unsucessfully. No documentation is available for mm-carrierwave  and I was unable to set up the initializer. Is there any other way how to upload the files to S3?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)? It allows for your storage location to be on S3 with some help from  the gem 'aws-sdk'.

Here is a tutorial: [Paperclip and MongoMapper](http://www.bencurtis.com/2009/08/paperclip-and-mongomapper/)

Comment: Thank you for your post. I failed with paperclip as well. I feel that I will switch to mongoid soon.

Comment: What is the issue you are having? What if you tried Paperclip local at first. Just make sure it is saving the image locally. Once that is working then try to push to S3. I think you might have better results that way.